# Using ggmap in R for Geocoding API and exceed API limit after only 2 requests

Tags: r, google-maps, ggplot2, google-cloud-platform, ggmap

I'm trying to work through a Lynda.com tutorial on ggplot2 and there's a section that uses Google's Geocoding API with the ggmap library. I have an API key that I've registered in my code as below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggmap)

register_google(key="myApiKey")
qmap("New York, NY", zoom = 7)
nyc_map <- get_map("New York, NY", zoom = 10)
```

After it worked once, every attempt to call after that gets this message:

> Warning: Geocoding "New York, NY" failed with error: You have exceeded
>   your rate-limit for this API.

How can this be exceeding the rate limit after only two calls? (I've called about a dozen times over 3 more days, but it follows the same pattern - it works once per day and then not at all with the above error message).

Even though calling this API literally a handful of times for studying purposes seems like far less than would be required for paid plan, I still tried giving Google my billing info, made sure the billing account is linked to the project, made sure my quota limits are set far above twice per day, but still no luck.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Are you geocoding, or trying to plot a map?

Comment: I'm trying to plot a map. My understanding of the qmap() function is that it grabs the lat / long coordinates (the portion that calls on the geocoding API) and then goes straight to plotting the map, which is my goal. Since it calls on the API, it fails with "You have exceeded your rate-limit for this API."

Comment: Are you sure your API key enabled on the Geocoding API?

Answer (score 0):

Are you firing your requests too fast? From https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/previous-licenses/articles/usage-limits :

> If you exceed the usage limits you will get an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT status
>   code as a response.
>
> This means that the web service will stop providing normal responses
>   and switch to returning only status code OVER_QUERY_LIMIT until more
>   usage is allowed again. This can happen:
>
> ```
> Within a few seconds, if the error was received because your application sent too many requests per second.
> Within the next 24 hours, if the error was received because your application sent too many requests per day. The daily quotas are reset at midnight, Pacific Time.
> ```

I don't know the ggmap library what it does internally but maybe there is a setting that you can throttle the requests.